# Failing to find optimal linear fit in R with lm

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, lm

I have three linear regression models in R:

```
 1. lm(Y~X1)
 2. lm(Y~X2)
 3. lm(Y~X2+X3)
```

Of note, in this data mathematically `X1=(X2+X3).`

`Model 1` gives `Adjusted R^2=0.100` and `p=0.023`. `Model 2` gives `Adjusted R^2=0.096` and `p=0.025`.

Here's the confusing part to me. `Model 3` shows that only `X2` is significant and the model as a whole shows `Adjusted R^2=0.078` and `p=0.078`. **Why would that be?** If `Model 1` has the best `R^2`, I would think variables `X2` and `X3` would both be significant to reproduce that or at best the model would find a solution with `Adjusted R^2` of at least `0.100` as per `Model 1`, since `X1=(X2+X3)`.

[image]

Comment: You have an issue in your data. Does X3 have missing values? How did you handle those when calculating X1?

Comment: Y, X1, X2, and X3 all have no missing data. See updated screenshot.

Comment: lm(Y~X1) will be identical to lm(Y~ I(X2 + X3)) but not to lm(Y~X2 + X3). This is not how multiple regression works.

Comment: We need the details, please: how exactly is $Y$ supposed to be related to $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$?  How many observations are in your dataset?  It's easily possible for the inclusion of $X_3$ to reduce adjusted R-squared *greatly* when there are few observations and $X_3$ is strongly correlated with $X_2.$

Comment: Re the edit: you err by an order of magnitude in reporting the adjusted R-squared in model 2!

Comment: @kmm yes that did come out to be identical. But now I don't have a p value for X2 and X3 separately.

Comment: @whuber sorry just a typo. Updated!

Comment: Also, please note that you could redefine  $X_3 = X_2+X_3,$ showing that your question comes down to "how can a model with one explanatory variable ($X_2$) have a different $R^2$ than a model with a different explanatory variable $(X_3)$?"  I hope the answer to that is obvious!

Comment: @whuber X2 and X3 are not correlated. (p=0.34)

Comment: Testing for correlation is completely irrelevant.  What matters for fitting is the *specific relationship* that holds among the variables, not some hypothesis about their data-generation process.

Comment: @whuber I was just referring to your comment about "when there are few observations and X3 is strongly correlated to X2"

Comment: That's right.  The relevant sense of "strongly correlated" is the magnitude of the correlation coefficient, not the p-value of a test.  But now that you have corrected the typo, the nature of your question changes dramatically.  Moreover, pay attention to my observation about redefining $X_3:$ it shows the question is without any content.

Comment: @whuber thanks for explaining! See answer below and my question about reconciling two very different conclusions. Thoughts?

Comment: What are the "very different conclusions"?

Comment: @whuber The conclusion that X2 and X3 (i.e., X1 in Model 1) together lead to a higher R^2 than X2 alone (i.e., Model 2), versus the conclusion that X3 is useless and only X2 is significant (i.e., Model 3). How do you reconcile that?

Comment: I see nothing to reconcile!  For extensive discussions on the relationships among variables in multiple regression and changes of statistical significance when variables are included and excluded, [this search works well](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=regression%20significant%20not%20change%20score%3a5&searchOn=3).

Comment: @whuber Let me ask a different way. Based on the above R code in my question, does X3 have any relationship to Y?

Comment: That's a clear question. The answer is that your code doesn't investigate it directly.  *After controlling for $X_2,$* you have no evidence of a relationship.  But to address your question you ought to consider comparing the model `Y ~ X3` to `Y ~ X2 + X3`.  And even before going through such formalities, please examine a scatterplot matrix of the $(X_2,X_3,Y)$ triples to *see* what the relationships might be.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, but doesn't comparing Y~X3 to Y~X2+X3 test the effect of X2?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are confusing the coefficient of determination and the adjusted $R^2$.

An adjusted $R^2$ takes account of the total degrees of freedom of an analysis. Model 3 has an additionl degree of freedom. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

$$\bar{R}^2 = 1 - \dfrac{SS_{res}/df_{res}}{SS_{tot}/df_{tot}}$$

The null model has 1 degree of freedom for the intercept, whereas the Model 3 has 3 degrees of freedom for the 3 model parameters (intercept, and coefficients to X2 and  X3), and your models 1 and 2 have only 2 degrees of freedom. If $X_1$ has no predictive value at all (after adjusting for $X_2$), the adjusted $R^2$ will *reduce* after including it as a covariate in the model. The $R^2$ in this case will remain unchanged.

Comment: If the inclusion of X2 and X3 leads to a higher R^2, why would they both not be significant? The output of Model 3 to me suggests that X2 is the only important variable, however Model 2 with X2 alone has a worse R^2.

Comment: @CodeGuy there are 4 significance tests shown in the model 3 output. Their nulls, respectivel are: intercept = 0 (p=0.39), coef of X2 = 0(p=0.02), coef of X3 = 0 (p=0.67), and lastly coef of X2 = coef of X3 = 0 (p =0.07). The X3 coef is so useless the extra degree of freedom cost the global test too much. In other words, if the null is true, the predictiveness of *two* random and unrelated covariates is expected to be better than *one* random & unrelated covariate. This is because OLS optimizes fit. If we update our critical value, the Model 3 global test fails to show significance.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Based on Model 1, clearly, including both X2 and X3 (i.e., when we mathematically add them together) leads to a better R^2. But Model 3 leads us to think X3 is useless. How do we reconcile these two conclusions?

Comment: @CodeGuy the assumptions in the creation of X1 were favorable.

Comment: @CodeGuy furthermore, not that you have tested it formally, but there's no evidence to suggest a model adjusting only for X2 is better than X1. They both yield $R^2=0.12$, though X1 is a *bit* better, you're dealing with N=40.

Comment: How would you test that formally, that Model 1 is better than Model 2? Doing anova(lm(Y~X1),lm(Y~X2)) does not provide a p-value.

Comment: You need to save the regressions as objects first.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand what do you mean? That doesn’t change anything.

Comment: @AdamO How would you test that formally? (Sorry forgot to tag you in the last comment in response to your comment)

Comment: @CodeGuy it's a complicated bit of R programming, it should be a second question.

Comment: @AdamO I'm not asking for the R programming, if that helps. I'm asking for statistics of comparing two models, Y~X1 and Y~X2, given that an ANOVA would not work since DF are identical.